# How to change cwd(current working directory) when calling erl_tar:create function?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Like the `create_option`: `cwd` in the `zip.create/3`: http://erlang.org/doc/man/zip.html#create-3

Unfortunately, `erl_tar:create` does not have this option. Am I able to change cwd when calling erl_tar:create?

Comment: Can you try with http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#set_cwd-1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to cwd option doc what it's doing is just to prepend filenames with directory, you can do the same in `erl_tar:create`, e.g. by changing the filename from `'test.tar'` to `'../test.tar'`

> Uses the specified directory as current work directory (cwd). This is prepended to filenames when adding them, although not in the zip archive (acting like file:set_cwd/1 in Kernel, but without changing the global cwd property.).

changing cwd sounds dangerous since it may result in runtime errors if you are using some other files in your current cwd (or relative to your current cwd).

Comment: Yeah, I use '../root_dir/file_name' or absolute path got the same effect as change cwd. Thank you!